# KeyCloak Visual Studio

Tags: c#, keycloak

I am getting an error when I login using KeyCloak.

The error I get is "**Both the access token and the refresh token have expired**"

I have followed the example detailed here;
https://github.com/dylanplecki/KeycloakOwinAuthentication/wiki/ASP.NET-MVC-Tutorial

The code works as far as the login page.  I enter my login ID and Password, press the Login button and immediately get the above error on a yellow screen.

I have created the client in the Master realm and based all the settings according to what is in the web page above.

Does anyone know what I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was confirmed as a bug:

https://github.com/dylanplecki/KeycloakOwinAuthentication/issues/35#issuecomment-204128345

Are you still having issues?

Comment: Thanks for this.  We have stopped testing for the time being but we'll be back onto this as of next week.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what you need to do in order to resolve this, and use Keycloak normally:
Since it is reported as a bug, and The Library Author/maintainer is not working on it anymore, you'll have to fix your local copy, and use it instead of the NuGet package.

Background:
Keycloak uses UTC time in all attributes that require time reference, like for example the Token's `nbf` or `exp`. Since the Access token is usually valid for 5 minutes, so unless if the machine happens to be in a time zone that matches UTC time, you'll never be able to make the 5 minute limit.
The problem with the library is that it compares the time in the token with `DateTime.Now` you need to change that manually into `DateTime.UtcNow`

Implementation:
You can download a copy of the Library Code from GitHub [here](https://github.com/dylanplecki/KeycloakOwinAuthentication) and browse through the first project in the solution: `KeycloakIdentityModel` to the file where the task is located: `KeycloakIdentity.cs`.
Go to line 443, that's the beginning of comparison task `GetClaimsAsync`.

inside the task, there is an if statement, you'll change all `DateTime.Now` within into `DateTime.UtcNow`. the result should look like this:

```
// Check to update cached claims, but not if refresh token is missing (as in bearer mode)
            if ((_kcClaims == null || _accessToken.ValidTo <= DateTime.UtcNow) && _refreshToken != null)
            {
                // Validate refresh token expiration
                if (_refreshToken.ValidTo <= DateTime.UtcNow)
                    throw new Exception("Both the access token and the refresh token have expired");

                // Load new identity from token endpoint via refresh token
                await RefreshIdentity(_refreshToken.RawData);
            }
```

changes took place in lines 439 and 442.

after that rebuild the solution, and browse to the physical folders of the solution to ~\src\Owin.Security.Keycloak\bin\Debug, Make sure that the date modified on both of them resembles the actual time and copy both files 
`KeycloakIdentityModel.dll` and `Owin.Security.Keycloak.dll` to an easy directory to reach (this is not necessary, but recommended for simplicity).

Then from your solution, delete both from the references and add the new ones by right clicking on the reference node in the solution explorer and selecting Add reference. Browse to where you saved them, add them and it should function correctly this way.